# What is the difference between Used and Allocated space?

Tags: t-sql, disk-space

I am learning Database operations and I have found a couple of resources online that have given me a loose understanding, but I still couldn't explain the difference myself. Explain like I am five please. I want to make sure that I have a solid foundation to expand my knowledge upon.

Answer (score 5):

Think of your database like a bucket.

The ALLOCATED space is how big the bucket is, i.e. how much data it can hold.

The USED space is how much water/data is actually inside the bucket.

When the water gets to the top of the bucket, you need to make the bucket bigger by allocating more space.

Comment: So, unallocated space is how big the bucket can potentially be, and free space is the space left in the bucket? I am sure that these questions are obvious. I thank you for the analogy, it made it very clear.

Answer (score 1):

When talking about memory storage, the Hotel analogy also works well.

But in this kind of hotel only one person is allowed in a room at a time; a man or a woman. This represents bit data. Ones and zeros.

The max capacity of the hotel is 512 people.
Before your hotel opens you decide to allocate only half of your rooms for guests. The allocated space is 256, and the unallocated space is the remaining 256. All the rooms are still empty. Just because you allocate space doesn't mean you have filled it.

Now, let's assume you have a massive line outside your hotel, but your lobby can only have 6 people in it at a time. 
This represents byte data. Which is usually how computer data is interpreted; in chunks of 6. So you let the first 6 people in and assign them rooms.

- Now your used space = 6
- Your allocated space still = 256
- Your unallocated space = 256
- And your max capacity = 512

After you fill all 256 rooms, you cannon fill the rest of your capacity until you allocate more space.